# Can I use ormlite to dynamically generate the DAO layer on Android?

Tags: android, dynamic-data, dao, ormlite, dynamic-ui

I'm trying to solve [this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461191/creating-screens-and-underlying-data-access-layer-dynamically-on-android) I was wondering if it's possible to use ORMLite (or modify it) to support this use case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/) and forget all the sql and mappings hassle. Model your objects and persist them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you could create a table of screens which could then have a field table with the name of the screen-id, field name, and other information.  You could have a user-id in the screen table so each user could have an entry which corresponds to a list of fields.

```
public class Screen {
  String user;
  ...
}

public class Field {
    Screen screen;
    String fieldName;
    int fieldPosition;
    ...
}
```

But unless you actually need SQL functionality, you may want to consider a different persistence strategy like @mgv mentioned.